# How to have multiple data layers in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to have multiple data layers using Google Maps API? The only existing related question I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275265/interact-with-geojson-layers-independently-in-google-maps-api-v3).

Here's my problem.

I want to have a data layer for showcasing polygons on map that are being drawn by the user. At the same time I want to have another data layer that displays polygons that already exist in a database.

I figured I would do this by creating 2 data layers:

```
drawLayer = new google.maps.Data();
savedLayer = new google.maps.Data();
```

But when I initialize the drawing tools using `drawLayer.setControls(['Polygon'])`, it doesn't work. If I replace the `drawLayer` with `map.data`, then the drawing tools works fine. Why is that?

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/pjaLdz6w/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your fiddle you aren't declaring `drawLayer` as a `google.maps.Data` object. But even if you do, you still need to give it a map attribute:

```
drawLayer = new google.maps.Data({map:map});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jbyd815y/

Comment: Oh dear. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks for your help.